# Elastic Map Reduce node.js bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: node.js, amazon-emr

https://raw.github.com/AmazonEMR/bootstrap.actions/master/node/install-node-bin-x86.sh

That simply just. doesn't. work.

downloads that file. Add:
node --version

At end of it.

"On the master instance (i-d6c6a28b), bootstrap action 1 returned a non-zero return code"

Comment: No one? This is sad...

Comment: @Artiom I actually have node.js hadoop stream MR running now. Please see answer. (Was actually pretty stupid, so I didn't bother posting)

Comment: I've fix my issue. I has same problem: on Amazon EMR with Hadoop, Node.js instaled with custom bootstraping, Problem was that i work in Windows VS2013 and my Mapper and Reducer was saving with Windows CL LF instead of Unix LF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script works.

Adding the

```
node --version
```

Doesn't work because the path to node executable was appended as environment variable for your bash. This does not take effect until next time you sign in.

What was chocking for me was that the example from AWS was bad.

https://github.com/AmazonEMR/sample.apps/blob/master/node/sample-mapper.js

Some how

```
process.stderr.write(err);
```

doesn't work.

Edit- Try running that install-node-bin-x86.sh line by line through ssh. It will all run fine. Node --version still doesn't work. BUT. log out the SSH session and connect again. Then do 'Node --version' it will work.